# Low-profile PCI network interface card with Windows 2003 64 bit drivers

Tags: hardware

Can anyone recommend one of the above?

Cheers, Rob

Comment: PCI, PCI-X or PCIe? if the first two what speed/bits? how many ports on the card and at what speed?

Comment: Oh and do you need advanced features like TOE, iSCSI-acceleration, PXE, jumbo frames etc?

Comment: Do you need copper or fibre ports?

Comment: PCI as stated in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to provide more details.

If I was assume that you aren't looking for anything unusual, then you might want this.

Intel PWLA8391GTL 10/100/1000Mbps PCI PRO/1000 GT Low Profile Desktop Adapter
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106122

Comment: Thanks that was a perfect recommendation. Although I'm at a loss as to why the self-styled moderators of this system decided it wasn't a real question...